# File truncate operation in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

What is the best-practice way to truncate a file in Java? For example this dummy function, just as an example to clarify the intent:

```
void readAndTruncate(File f, List<String> lines)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    for (Scanner s = new Scanner(f); s.hasNextLine(); lines.add(s.nextLine())) {}

    // truncate f here! how?

}
```

The file can not be deleted since the file is acting as a place holder.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [FileChannel.truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate-long-):

```
try (FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream(f, true).getChannel()) {
  outChan.truncate(newSize);
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing simple `try { new FileOutputStream(f).getChannel().truncate(0).close(); } catch (IOException e) { /* log and ignore */ }`. Question: does it matter if file is opened with append==true, or not?

Comment: Then just `new FileWriter(f).close()`.

Comment: If you open without append == `true` th file gets immediately truncated (wha you want).

Comment: Just opening a FileOutputStream without using append == true will cause the file to be truncated (at least on openjdk on linux).  So new FileOutputStream( path ).close(); will cause it to be truncated on my system.

Comment: I prefer the FileChannel approach, as it does not rely on side effect when closing the output stream. Also a better option as it makes the code more maintainable: There is no confusion what should happen when calling channel.truncate(newSize). So many bugs hide under the heading of a series of unintentional consequences.

Answer (score 15):

One liner using [Files.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)...

```
Files.write(outFile, new byte[0], StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

Can use [File.toPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--) to convert from File to Path prior as well.

Also allows other **StandardOpenOptions**.

Answer (score 8):

`new FileWriter(f)` will truncate your file upon opening (to zero bytes), after that you can write lines to it

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you're going to write to the file, but the simplest way is to open a new [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) without specifying that you plan to append to the file (note: the base `FileOuptutStream` constructor will truncate the file, but if you want to make it clear that the file's being truncated, I recommend using the two-parameter variant).

Comment: Not going to write to the file, just want to truncate it to zero... It is read and processed, contents need to be cleared to avoid eating disk space, but file entry should remain.

Comment: Yeah, `FileOutputStream` truncating makes sense, but I wonder why the docs don't mention it (they just say file will be written from beginning, without specifying what happens to previous file contents).

Answer (score 2):

`RandomAccessFile.setLength()` seems to be exactly what's prescribed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RandomAccessFile#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) and push the bytes recorded in this way into a new `File` object.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(myFile,myMode);  
byte[] numberOfBytesToRead = new byte[truncatedFileSizeInBytes];  
raf.read(numberOfBytesToRead);    
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);  
fos.write(numberOfBytesToRead);
```

Comment: I think using RandomAccessFile would allow reading and then truncating with single file opening, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons IO API:

```
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.write(new File(...), "", Charset.defaultCharset());
```