# Delete file android

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I am trying to delete a file but it doesn't work. I don't know why. Here is my function calls. `String ola` and `ola2` both have `mozi` although you can see I have deleted the file after `ola` line is executed. I expect `ola2` to give me `null`.

```
    OfflineDataFiles dataFiles = new  OfflineDataFiles();
    dataFiles.writeToFile("mozi", getApplicationContext(), 1);
    String ola =dataFiles.readFromFile(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    boolean answer=dataFiles.DeleteFile(1);
    String ola2 =dataFiles.readFromFile(getApplicationContext(), 1);
```

**Delete File :**

```
public boolean DeleteFile(int filetype)
{
    File f = new File("myfile.txt");
    boolean ans= f.delete();
     return ans;
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: That's for you to tell us - what *is* the problem??  If you are saying that you can still read from the file after deleting it, this is actually *expected behavior* - a deleted file does not actually become inaccessible until the last file handle to it is closed.  And even then, trying to read from a closed file handle does not necessarily have defined behavior in all implementations.

Comment: @Chris Sratton , I actually wanted to empty the file so that there would be no data left in it. So that's why I am trying to delete it. But as I said in the last phrase above , I was expecting the last read function to return null as I've called the `DeleteFile()`.How can I close the last file handle here ? I thought File object is in the function scope. It should get deleted after the function returns no ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `myfile.txt` doesn't have the path where it is stored

It should be something like

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();   
String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/yourfolder/" ;
File f = new File(path +"myfile.txt");
f.delete();
```

Comment: @Mj1992 your delete doesn't specify the location

Answer (score 1):

Delete width the right method:

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

The selectedFilePath for example: /sdcard/download/curse.txt

The very best.

Answer (score -1):

[FileChannel.truncate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate%28long%29)

```
public boolean DeleteFile(int filetype) {
    File f = new File("myfile.txt");
    FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream(f, true).getChannel();
    outChan.truncate(0);
    outChan.close();
}
```

From: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280385/file-truncate-operation-in-java)
Create a reference to myfile.txt, than trunc it to 0 bytes. You will be able to access it but probably its contents are gone.