# Copy a file into an other starting from a specific position

Tags: java, java-io, truncation

I have the following file that exceeds a determined size, and i want to reduce it, but im interested the last lines of the file, so i want to delete the first lines until the size is equal to the permitted size,

is there anyway to do this in java  ?

Comment: You want to do it in place or a solution which rewrites the file is okay?

Comment: any suggestion is welcome

Comment: this answer looks good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280385/file-truncate-operation-in-java

Comment: i have already tried this, when i truncate it keeps the first lines not the last ones.

Comment: How about setting file pointer to end file minus max size and checking that's >= 0. and then read from there?

Comment: i think it reverse the lines order, and the file i am talking about is a log file, so i am interested to keep the same lines order.

Comment: it does keep the same line ordering

Comment: I see two alternatives: 1. Use a `RandomAccessFile`, set the file pointer directly after the block you want to be omitted. Then read some block of bytes, write them to the beginning of the file, then read the next byte-block and write it behind the first, and so on... At the end truncate the file. 2. Read the file with an `InputStream`. Read the first bytes and do nothing with them. Then write byte for byte (or better some byte blocks) to the `OutputStream`. Then delete the original file and move the output file to the original file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 512;

try(RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("Path to inputfile", "r"))
{
    long fileSize = file.length();

    long readStartPosition = fileSize - MAX_FILE_SIZE;
    if(readStartPosition < 0)
    {
        readStartPosition = 0;
    }

    file.seek(readStartPosition);

    try(OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Path to outputfile")))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for(int bytesRead = file.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1; bytesRead = file.read(buffer))
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
catch(Throwable t)
{
    System.out.println(t);;
}
```

Or this, if you want to keep the same file:

```
long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 512;

try(RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("Path to inputfile", "rw"))
{
    long fileSize = file.length();

    long readStartPosition = fileSize - MAX_FILE_SIZE;
    if(readStartPosition < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    long writePosition = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    file.seek(readStartPosition);
    for(int bytesRead = file.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1; bytesRead = file.read(buffer))
    {
        long currentPosition = file.getFilePointer();

        file.seek(writePosition);
        file.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        writePosition += bytesRead;

        file.seek(currentPosition);
    }

    long newSize = file.length() - readStartPosition;
    file.setLength(newSize);
}
catch(Throwable t)
{
    System.out.println(t);;
}
```

NOTE: Both examples are written on the top of my head, but they should work. At least you get the hang of it.