# Deleting last n-bytes from a file

Tags: java, file, byte

I'm wondering if there is a way to delete n-bytes from the end of the file
without writting the whole file again.

In the university that i'm studing, our professor told us to create a data structure using the Hashing technique that will be able to search, insert and remove data VERY fast!!! I found a way to swap any data from the
file with the last data in it(which is stored at the end of the file) without destroying my data structure. So after swapping the data i just need to delete the last 16 bytes from the file to free space from the hard disk (my data are 16-bytes wide). This swapping technique is similar to the binary trees deletion technique.

The problem is that i don't know a way to delete these last 16 bytes.
I know that the simple way is to write again the file from byte 0 to
fileSize - 16, but this is a VERY VERY slow method. If the data structure has
thousands of data it will take years to re-write the file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280385/file-truncate-operation-in-java

Comment: @AndyTurner OP does not want to rewrite the file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why'd you mark it as the duplicate then? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner I read the question you linked to, not the answer.  Next time please link directly to the answer using the "Share" link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14280385/3788176 @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not quite sure what the difference is between the two links (other than the short "q") - would you mind enlightening me? :)

Comment: Try this link instead:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14280471/53897