# Which mode for RandomAccessFile() overwrites existing file?

Tags: java

I want to write to a file called `myFile.txt` each time I open my program. If a file with that name from a previous run of the program exists, I want it to be overwritten. How do I accomplish this? I've read about:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.txt", "rw");
```

but does this overwrite existing files? The documentation doesn't tell me if it does. Note that it's important that the old file be deleted in its entirety, I don't want the end of it to still be there if I only overwrite half of its length in the current run.

**EDIT:**
Through testing I found out that "rw" doesn't delete existing file, it only overwrites for the top of the file and leaves the rest of it.

I found an alternative solution to fit my needs:

```
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.txt", "rw");
    file.setLength(0);
    file.write(contentBytes);
```

But it would be nice if it was possible to do it in a shorter way.

Comment: It does open in append. But you still must seek to the end. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Appendingdatatoexistingfile.htm

Comment: Could you clarify? Not sure I understand the code example.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can set the length of file to zero  and expect the file is empty - why don't you just overwrite 'file' with new file (same path, name, extension)?

Comment: It does seem to truncate it. Test on your own machine. On mine it does. What do you mean with "just overwrite..."? I tried `new RandomAccessFile("myFile.txt", "rw");` and started writing but it didn't delete old contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File truncate operation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280385/file-truncate-operation-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

`RandomAccessFile` does not have an opening mode that removes the file on opening. You can truncate it right after opening by calling `setLength(0)`, the way your suggested. You can also get `FileChannel` and call `truncate(0)` on it.

If you use `RandomAccessFile` only to write `contentBytes` array, you can simplify your code by using `FileOutputStream`, which truncates the file on opening (unless you explicitly request file appending):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(contentBytes);
```

> The reason I use RandomAccessFile is that is allows me to get the position of the file pointer, which I need in my application.

You should be able to get the position from `FileOuputStream` like this:

```
long pos = fos.getChannel().position();
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The reason I use RandomAccessFile is that is allows me to get the position of the file pointer, which I need in my application.