# Clear Contents of a .txt file which is already being used in Java Program

Tags: java, file

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("CustomLogsOutput.txt");
PrintWriter logsPrintStream = new PrintStream(fileOutputStream);
```

This is the code that I am using to make an Object of PrintWriter which, as the name suggest, is used to dump logs in a file.

Now the logs are very large, and I am using this program on a free server, where we have storage limits. It might get big enoungh in 30 days, that I might run into storage issues.

Althogh, it is not a good practice, but for other reasons too, i want to make a function which, when called, will clear the contents of the log file `CustomLogsOutput.txt`. But I don't want to close the `PrintWriter` at all. Neither can i afford to delete the file, otherwise `PrintWriter` might give an FileNotFoundException.

How can I clear the content of the file `CustomLogsOutput.txt` that will just clear the file and not affect any other part of the program?

Till now, this file is accessed only by the code provided above.

Comment: It is not a good idea to keep resources open. What if there was a network partitioning happen or something crashed from which you are reading. Why cant you used sometime like `ELK` stack so that you also have access to logs and also be able to manage your data.

Comment: Try `FileChannel.truncate` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280385/file-truncate-operation-in-java/14280471 .. what happens may vary OS to OS .. for instance on older windows even if you flush a stream the OS can take quite some time for it to show up in directory listings as non-zero size ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the `PrintWriter` and create a new instance using the same file name.

```java
PrintWriter logsPrintStream = new PrintWriter("CustomLogsOutput.txt");
/*
 * When you want to truncate the file then execute the following code.
 */
logsPrintStream.close();
logsPrintStream = new PrintWriter("CustomLogsOutput.txt");
```

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.lang.String-):

> Parameters:
> fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size